# How do I preserve variable values between HTML files?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a page that refers to a `.js` file. In that file I have the following code that sets the value of a variable:

```
var foo;

function bar()
    {
    foo = //some value generated by some type of user input
    }

bar();
```

Now I'd like to be able to navigate to another page that refers to the same script, and have this variable retain the value set by `bar()`. What's the best way to transport the value of this variable, assuming the script will be running anew once I arrive on the next page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use cookies.

> Cookies were originally invented by
>   Netscape to give 'memory' to web
>   servers and browsers. The HTTP
>   protocol, which arranges for the
>   transfer of web pages to your browser
>   and browser requests for pages to
>   servers, is state-less, which means
>   that once the server has sent a page
>   to a browser requesting it, it doesn't
>   remember a thing about it. So if you
>   come to the same web page a second,
>   third, hundredth or millionth time,
>   the server once again considers it the
>   very first time you ever came there.
>
> This can be annoying in a number of
>   ways. The server cannot remember if
>   you identified yourself when you want
>   to access protected pages, it cannot
>   remember your user preferences, it
>   cannot remember anything. As soon as
>   personalization was invented, this
>   became a major problem.
>
> Cookies were invented to solve this
>   problem. There are other ways to solve
>   it, but cookies are easy to maintain
>   and very versatile.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the value in the query string.
When the user navigate to the other page append the value to the query string and load it in the next.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).  jStorage is probably better used for cached data and lossy user preferences (e.g. saved username in a login form), as it doesn't have *full* browser support (but IE6+ and most other common browsers support it) and cannot be relied upon (like cookies).

Answer (score 0):

You can use YUI's Cookie Library http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/cookie/